# Modify files inside multiple zip files using Maven

Tags: maven, ant-contrib, maven-antrun-plugin

Today I wanted to perform this task, and I run across some issues in the way. So I present here my problem and the solution I found. Perhaps somebody knows a simpler solution!

The problem was this: I was trying to build a distribution package of a Java project which is built with Maven2. In a previous step, several zip files all containing a file named manifest.xml in the root were generated, and I wanted to modify this XML file in all this ZIP files. This is a scheme:

```
package-file-1.zip
|- contents(DIR)
\- manifest.xml

package-file-2.zip
|- contents(DIR)
\- manifest.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example modifies the zip files in `${zip.sourcedir}` replacing the string `&` with `&amp;` in the file manifest.xml of all this zip files and places the modified zip files in the directory `target`.

For that, it uses the `maven-antrun-plugin` including the `for` and `var` tasks from the `antcontrib` tasks(http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net). This permits to unzip the contents of every zip file into a separate directory. Note also the use of the task `basename` to extract the name of the zip files out of their path.

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-and-repair-zips</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>                          
      <configuration>                           
        <tasks>                               
          <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
          <for param="filepath">
            <path>
                 <fileset dir="${zip.sourcedir}" includes="**/*.zip"/>
            </path>
            <sequential>
                    <var name="for.filename" unset="true" />
                    <basename property="for.filename" file="@{filepath}" />

                    <unzip src="@{filepath}" dest="target/repair-temp/${for.filename}" encoding="UTF8" />

                    <replace file="target/repair-temp/${for.filename}/manifest.xml" token="&amp;" value="&amp;amp;" encoding="UTF8" />

                    <zip basedir="target/repair-temp/${for.filename}" destfile="target/${for.filename}" encoding="UTF8" />
            </sequential>
          </for>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
      <version>1.0b3</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ant</groupId>
          <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

In order to write this solution, I got the needed knowledge from this URLs:

- Modify a JAR(or ZIP) file using Ant: [How do I modify a file in a jar file using ANT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737560/how-do-i-modify-a-file-in-a-jar-file-using-ant)
- Unzip multiple files into separate directories: http://grokbase.com/t/ant.apache.org/user/2004/01/re-how-to-unzip-multiple-file-into-separate-directories/122a5ezxhh6eolf5enkrdfgryika
- Use ant-contrib in Maven2: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Antrun+Plugin

  - But be careful to use `net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml` instead of `net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties` to be able to use the `for` task
- Use the ant-contrib `var` task: http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1374074

#### Edit

After posting the question, I was able to find a couple of questions related, that could help if one is having problems implementing a similar thing:

- [maven3 - maven-antrun-plugin - "failed to create task or type if"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760120/maven3-maven-antrun-plugin-failed-to-create-task-or-type-if)
- [Using antcontrib <if> task via maven-antrun-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724007/using-antcontrib-if-task-via-maven-antrun-plugin)