# maven, maven-antrun-plugin, parametrization via properties

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm building maven projects which all need to download, unzip and move several files during the build process. Therefore I'm using an ant script run via `maven-antrun-plugin`. As this workflow needs to be executed in multiple projects, I would like to place the ant script in a parent `pom.xml` and only do some parametrization in the child `pom.xml` files, where I define the actual files to be downloaded (which are different, because I build platform-specific projects).

The ant script which should go to the parent `pom.xml` looks something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <mkdir dir="${directory.download}"/>
                    <get dest="${directory.download}">
                        <!-- 
                              this part should be variable and contains 
                              different number of URLs in each child project 
                        -->
                        <url url="http://example.com/binary1-win64.zip"/>
                        <url url="http://example.com/binary2-win64.zip"/>
                        <url url="http://example.com/binary3-win64.zip"/>
                    </get>
                    <!-- lots of further tasks, such as unzip, rename, etc. -->
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The only variable part in above's script is the ant `get` task. It would be nice, if I could simply pass the list of URLs to download as maven `properties` in the concrete child projects. As a have a varying number of URLs however, I would need some "collection" property, which obviously does not exist. Instead, I tried passing a comma-separated list of URLs:

```
<properties>
    <urls.to.download>http://example.com/binary1-win64.zip,http://example.com/binary2-win64.zip,http://example.com/binary3-win64.zip</urls.to.download>
</properties>
```

… and then split the list using a `for` task in ant:

```
<for param="url" list="${urls.to.download}">
    <sequential>
        <get dest="${directory.download}">
            <url>${url}</url>
        </get>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

This however fails, because the `for` task does not seem to be supported by the `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
An Ant BuildException has occured: Problem: failed to create task or type for
[ERROR] Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERROR] Action: Check the spelling.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Are there any alternative approaches or a way, to make the `for` task work?

Comment: Yes, you need to include `ant-contrib`. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13701310/1743880

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Feel free to add this as an answer!

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to flag it as a duplicate instead. It avoids to repeat the same answers :) (FYI I don't see a better to way to do it).