# Maven 3 :How to copy a file to test directory , when the file does not exist

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant, maven-3, maven-plugin

I want to copy a file from src directory to test/resource directory during maven phase test, if and only if file does not exists in test/resource directory.Does any body know how we can achieve this ?Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Here's an updated version of @Saif Asif's answer that is working for me on Maven3:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpathref="maven.dependency.classpath" />
                    <if>
                        <available file="/path/to/your/file "/>
                        <then>
                            <!-- Do something with it -->
                            <copy file="/your/file" tofile="/some/destination/path" />
                        </then>
                    </if>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701310/1410035 for the "adding dependencies to the plugin" solution.

The noteworthy changes in this example are:

- Updated the plugin to version 1.8 (latest at the time of writing)
- Updated the taskdef to have the classpathref as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/4372491/1410035
- Changed the taskdef classpathref to work with maven3 as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13569218/1410035

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I wouldn't be able to do this without you. Even after 15y of being professional developer, I still cannot follow maven documentation(a.k.a complete disorganized garbage). The amount of time I wasted there trying to find something super trivial, which should be readily readable there, ... it will be at least weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`copy-maven-plugin`](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin) with `runIf` where check if the file exists.

Comment: Thanks @UR6LAD, This plugin done the job well.File copy is working as expected.

Comment: ,Our client is not happy with this plugin... :( .They are saying that the plugin seems to introduce a sort-of procedural "scripting" to maven, which to me feels
like just the opposite of what maven distinguishes from e.g. ant.Core logic of plugin i have used is as follows.Please let me know if their are any other alternative.
<resource>
<runIf>{{ !new File( "src/test/resources/systemConfig.properties" ).exists() }}</runIf>
<targetPath>src/test/resources</targetPath> <file>development/env/systemConfig.properties</file>
</resource>. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Maven AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) to accomplish this. In your pom.xml, use something like

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
                        <if>
                            <available file="/path/to/your/file "/>
                            <then>
                                <!-- Do something with it -->
                                <copy file="/your/file" tofile="/some/destination/path" />
                            </then>
                        </if>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks @Saif  for the response.When i tried your code i am getting following exception.. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:
run (default) on project *****: An Ant BuildException has occured: Problem:
failed to create task or type if
[ERROR] Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERROR] Action: Check the spelling.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken pl
ace.

Comment: Have you defined any task named as antcontrib.properties ? If not, remove that line

Comment: AS you mentioned in your code , <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />.This is the only enyrty i am having in my pom.xml.I have tired removing this entry  from pom not build is executing fine.However copying is not working.Folowing piece of code i have used for file copy and its working fine.However its overriding destination file if their are some chnage in src.this hsoul not happen.<configuration>
<tasks>
<copy file="src/f.properties"  tofile="dest/f.properties " overwrite="false" />
</tasks>
</configuration>

Comment: you mean to say that it is not working with the if-then statement ?

Comment: Yes.It seams like Condition statement is not executing.

Comment: Thanks @Saif Asif.My issue is resolved with copy-maven-plugin.Thank you very much for your time.:)